# What are the units for rate of movement through time?

Tags: time

Thinking of time as the dimension orthogonal to depth, it seems logical that the rate at which a body moves through time could vary.  Do units exist for rate of movement through time?  The numerator seems clear (e.g. seconds), but what could the denominator be?

Comment: let me repeat the question: units for rate of movement through time? so how should we view movement (with respect to what parameter measuring the change?), 2nd rate (maybe frequency is sth close to that?, number of cycles with respect to that parameter?), then the units part of the question can follow from the previous points

Comment: if by time you mean evolution and change in general, then 'time' (or rate according to the question) as  a parameter in equations, has units of seconds and multiples of that (in S.I. and C.G.S. systems of units)

Comment: Another answer is that the 'rate' in the question refers to the velocity of an object (exactly the definition: 'change with respect to time')

Comment: Finally one can indeed have multiple times (eg in special relativity) where there is a proper time (of an object) and the time as dimension in space-time. This is a 3rd answer

Comment: There is no universal rate. We each 'time' at different rates, but we can compare 'your second' per 'my second', or 'per second on earth at sea level'

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking of **RATE** you already mean the flow of time.

So rate at which a body moves through time is not a physically correct statement.

According to the velocities of bodies **the perception of time may be different** but the **rate of flow of events** is TIME itself.